# New tags / tag edits [scummvm] [monkey-island-se] [monkey-island-2-se]

Tags: discussion, tags

I have made a number of suggested edits to categorise a small collection of questions better.

Firstly, I have tagged some questions with a new [scummvm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scummvm) tag.  This (once created) will represent the SCUMMVM software used to run games using the SCUMM engine.  This is because I found some questions specific to that tool.  One even has an answer from one of the devs.

Secondly, I have re-tagged some [monkey-island](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island) and [monkey-island-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2) questions to [monkey-island-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-se) and [monkey-island-2-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2-se) tags.  These are for questions specific to the Special Edition release (and absolutely not relevant to the original releases).

I thought I would mention it here as to not raise alarm bells across mods/reviewers.  And of course to discuss alternatives if needed.  My suggested edits affect under 10 questions.

---

**Update**

Most of my suggested edits have been accepted (new tags added, several re-tagged).  However, possibly due to reviewing before the new tags were created, some edits were not accepted.

Rather than re-edit and hope someone else accepts the changes I thought I would list the suggested edits here:

I think this question should be moved from the [monkey-island](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island) and [monkey-island-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2) tags to [monkey-island-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-se) and [monkey-island-2-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2-se) tags as the question is specific to the Special Editions:

[Is it possible to edit in-game text in Monkey Island special edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188865/is-it-possible-to-edit-in-game-text-in-monkey-island-special-edition)

This question also asks about the Special Edition version so would like to add (not replace) [monkey-island-2-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2-se):

[Where is Max hidden in Monkey Island 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/where-is-max-hidden-in-monkey-island-2)

I would also like to add the [monkey-island-2-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-2-se) tag to this question (I have not created a suggested edit for this question):

[How can I switch to Classic Mode on Monkey Island 2 Special Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/how-can-i-switch-to-classic-mode-on-monkey-island-2-special-edition)

Are these suggested edits okay to re-raise now we have new Special-Edition-specific tags?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Aequitas - Er, did I do good?  Like I said, more of a marker rather than silent "mass" edits.  Looking for answers such as "you idiot, what have you done!?" or "well done" I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't think there should be a [monkey-island-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-se), when the difference between the normal and special edition is mostly cosmetic. If we get a few questions that could be specifically tagged under [monkey-island-se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-island-se), fair enough, but to me, a couple don't really cut it. At the end of the day, you recognise that Monkey Island Special Edition is an alternate version of Monkey Island. You would recognise the tags correctly, as a result. They are essentially doing their job, without the need for change. That said, the addition has already been approved, which trumps my opinion.

It is good to see the amount of forethought you present. That said, meta is better suited for discussion. In regards to your first part, I would suggest either posting on here to ask for discussion on if it is a good idea *before* you suggest the edits, or otherwise ask why the edits may have been rejected.

---

In regards to the three edit suggestions;

**Is it possible to edit in-game text in Monkey Island special edition?**
**How can I switch to Classic Mode on Monkey Island 2 Special Edition?**

As far as I can tell, both of the above questions are specific to Special Edition. With the inclusion of the tag, **it would be appropriate to remove the original tag for the special edition tag**. Look at the context of the question, and ask yourself "would I run into this problem if I was playing the normal game". If the answer is 'no, that feature is not present in the original', or 'no, the original does not behave that way', then the special edition tag should be used by itself.

***Where is Max hidden in Monkey Island 2?***

In this case, it is hard to say. The primary question is "Where is Max", and as a side note, the user asks "is he in special edition?". I tend to ignore secondary questions when looking at this sort of thing, as secondary questions should not really be present in the first place. I leave this up to others interpretation. That said, according to the answer, **Sam and Max are not in the Special Edition**, due to a change in copyright and rights ownership, between the two releases. "Where is Max" should not be tagged as special edition, as Max is simply not in the special edition.

Comment: I am generally in agreement that 'Special Editions' or 'HD remixes' should not be separated from the main tag, unless in circumstances where the content is changed or different, which is definitely the case here. Thus I think the `[*-se]` tags are justified.

Answer (score 3):

"Well done" I guess.

---

Comment: not sure if people upvoting to wish OP "well done" or upvoting because of smartassness

Comment: I am entirely sincere.

Comment: Finding it hard not to be bias in selecting this as the accepted answer